# JoinTable is lost

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a the two following classes:

```
@Entity
class A {
  @Id
  private aId;
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "AB", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "aId", referencedColumnName = "aId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bId", referencedColumnName = "bId"))
  private Set<B> bSet;
}

@Entity
class B {
   @Id
   private bId;
}
```

I load the complete object structure from one database and then enters a new transaction on the second database to persist the structure again. However the "AB" table is left empty. This is very strange as "B" is persisted though I only explicitly persist "A". I have check that A-objects contains non empty sets of B, so that is not a problem.

This leaves me with the conclusion that Hibernate believes that "AB"-table should exist as both "A" and "B" already have their primary keys. Is there a way around this so I can get Hibernate to persist the join-table in the second database?

Comment: I have now tested this with EntityManager.merge() instead of EntityManager.persist(), and it works. But I am still unsure why the persist do not work...

Comment: What is the type of the aId and bId fields? The way you posted here would result in a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is happening because you are using proxy object.That is if you  create instances of A and B with new operator and then call persist ,Join table record will be created .But you are using object from obtained from entitymanager(these are proxy objects) so you have to merge object that way entitymanager will create new proxies of this objects.